# Use Regex to replace dashes and keep hyphens?

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace dashes with a full-stop (.). If the dash appears as a hyphen it should be ignored. E.g. `-ac-ac` with `.ac-ac`

I started with the following regex: `(?<!\s|\-)\-+|\-+(?!\s|\-)`

Comment: Something like that: ``(?<!\w)-(?!\w)`` ?

Comment: Why do you need regex for this, instead of string replacement?

Comment: I want to use regex to differentiate between a bullet point (dash) and hyphen (between words).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\B-|-\B
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z7tD4C/1).

The pattern matches

- `\B-` - a hyphen that is preceded by a non-word char or is at the start of a string
- `|` - or
- `-\B` - a hyphen that is followed by a non-word char or is at the end of a string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YFbirA):

```py
import re
text = "-ac-ac"
print( re.sub(r'\B-|-\B', '.', text) )
# => .ac-ac
```

If you want to only narrow this down to letter context, replace `\B` with negative lookarounds containing a letter pattern:

```
(?<![^\W\d_])-|-(?![^\W\d_])
```

See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/z7tD4C/5) and [Python demo](https://ideone.com/nGrfbD).